# Regular expressions - quantificators and capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

has anyone any idea why do I get full match of ".abcd" using the regex below on the string I posted? I imagine this regex to only capture ".abc" as a full match.

```
^(\.)([a-z]+){3}$

String: .abcd
```

Best regards:)

Comment: I must clarify - I know how to solve that. I just want to know why it does not work as it is right now.

Comment: You're matching `ab`, then `c`, then `d`. This is because `+` is greedy, so it'll match as many as possible (`abcd`), but the regex still wants to be satisfied (hasn't yet satisfied `{3}`), so it backtracks to match `d` and then again to match `c` to satisfy `{3}`

Comment: @ctwheels Why does it match ab pair first? And then single letters?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/c1QpxI/1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engine presumably works with your input as follows:

- match the dot, fine
- match `[a-z]+` => `abcd` => first repetition
- 2nd repetition => nothing => fail!
- backtrack `abcd => abc` => 1st rep
- match `[a-z]+` => `d` => 2nd rep
- 3rd rep => nothing => fail!
- backtrack `abc => ab` => 1st rep
- match `cd` => 2nd rep
- 3rd rep => nothing => fail!
- backtrack `cd => c` => 2nd rep
- match `d` => 3rd rep
- okay

In general, "quantified quantifiers" are very dangerous, because they involve lots of backtracking, see e.g. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

You're currently saying start with a `.` then have at least 3 letters then end.

People, or at least I, suck at reading regex but here is a cool webpage that turns it into a flow chart for you https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%5C.%29%28%5Ba-z%5D%2B%29%7B3%7D%24

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 0):

```
^\.[a-z]{3}$
```

This is the regex you need
dot followed by three small letters

Comment: That's not the question being asked, though.